# dynamic (variable) variables (as in php?)

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Variable” Variables in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187530/variable-variables-in-javascript)

I'm thinking surely there is a way to achieve dynamic or variable variables in JavaScript (jQuery)
much as one might in php where we might have...

```
<?php
$params = array("street", "city", "state","zip_code");
foreach($params as $key) $$key = some_function($key);
echo $city; // would output the result of some_function(city);
?>
```

but I can't see a way to accomplish similar in jQuery (JavaScript)
where I would like to have something like...

```
<script>
params =["street", "city", "state","zip_code"];
jQuery.each(params, function() {
    var var this = jQuery('#'+this).val();
});
alert(city);
</script>
```

Which (*of course*) doesn't work, but there must be a way?

Answer (score 3):

Using "variable variables" is never necessary in a language that doesn't suffer from PHP's limitations.

```
addr = {};
params =["street", "city", "state","zip_code"];
jQuery.each(params, function() {
    addr[this] = jQuery('#'+this).val();
});
alert(addr.city);
```

In Javascript, `addr["city"]` and `addr.city` refer to the same thing.

Comment: PHP has the same array capabilities you are using with JavaScript. Variable variables are simply added flexibility.

Comment: Okay. Cool... 
I kinda danced around something pretty similar, but your solution brings it into focus for me. Thanks
Though like Sam152, I prefer to think of variable variables as a
mode of flexibility

Comment: It seems that simply calling the dynamically generated variable $city (in the 'limited' PHP scenario) is much cleaner/simpler than remembering later to call addr["city"] or addr.city in the javascript version. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: Even in PHP variable variables are hardly *"necessary"*. The answer in PHP is to use an array, the same thing you're demonstrating here.

Comment: Dynamically generated variables make the code harder to compile (because the compiler can't know the names of all the variables that might exist at any given time), and slower to execute (because variable access has to look up by name instead of by index or something).

Answer (score 0):

Settled on the following (which is just a tad cleaner IMHO)

```
params =["street", "city", "state","zip_code"];
jQuery.each(params, function() {
    params[this] = jQuery('#'+this).val();
});
alert(params.city); // or params['city'];
```